# If $f(x)$ is a number function such that $f(3x)=x+1$ for every $x$, then $f(x)=$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)$ is a number function such that $f(3x)=x+1$ for every $x$, then $f(x)=$ ?

I am not sure how to approach the problem. When we increase the argument ($x$) $3$ times the value of the function becomes $x+1$. How can we use that? Thank you!

Comment: Let $y=3x$.  What's $f(y)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I didn't quite catch what you tried to tell me. Can you clarify it for me? Thank you!

Comment: What you need is a change of variable as in @J.W.Tanner's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = 3 x$ , then $x = \frac{1}{3} u $

Hence, $f(3x) = f(u) = x + 1 = \frac{1}{3} u + 1 $

Thus, $f(x) = \frac{1}{3} x + 1 $